# How do I stop a Facebook account from writing spam posts?

Tags: security, facebook

This week I've been trying to help a friend of a friend with her computer. The problem is that from time to time, her Facebook account starts posting posts, from her, that tells people how they can get a free iPhone by googling for a specific code and following the initial link that pops up.

Here's an *example* of what the message looks like, the original one is in Norwegian, so I translated it, but I also changed the code, I don't want anyone to propagate this spam any further with my help:

> Hi :D A few days ago it was mentioned on TV that you can get the new iPhone X for free in a very simple manner :) Just type this code into a Google search: HXC1234XYZ and click on the first link available at the top.......

My question is simply this: Does anyone know which mechanism they use for this specific thing? I am trying to rid her computer or whatnot of this problem so that her account no longer gets these posts.

**Bear in mind that I'm *specifically* not asking for how to troubleshoot this problem in the general sense, that's too broad, I want to know if anyone know exactly what is posting this very specific post so that I can remove that specific problem.**

Here's what I looked at:

1. Installed software, couldn't see anything out of place
2. Installed plugins in her browser, there was one there, "Important Browser Update", this was firefox. Firefox updates itself, I removed this one but I don't know conclusively that it was this plugin.
3. Tightened her security

   - Reset her Facebook and email password, and raised the complexity of her passwords from "laughable" to "strong"
   - Disabled the ability of all 3rd party apps or websites to connect to her Facebook account (Settings, Apps and websites, Preferences, Apps, websites and games), this was "turned on", I turned it off.
   - Removed two applications that were listed on the Facebook page as active (Settings, Apps and websites, Active apps and websites), Seedr and Pinterest (the latter is most likely the real deal but since she cannot remember ever using this app I removed it)
4. Made sure Windows was updated

Since I don't know exactly what causes the specific post in question, I don't know if these measures are enough or if there's something else I need to do.

Comment: I'd tend to vote to migrate this to Web Apps, but otherwise a reasonable question that can be generalized.

Comment: Does it only happen when the computer is powered on?

Comment: That is a good question, but her computer is rather quiet so she told me she always just leaves it on and lets the screen go into power saving mode.

Comment: I see the close votes and I would tend to agree but I think the question is going to be off topic on every site in the Stack Exchange network because it doesn't specifically involve only one thing. It is about web applications, Facebook, but it is also about Security, and most likely there is Software involved. As such, all sites can probably rightfully claim that it is off topic. I'm hoping to get an answer on at least one site so I'll happily migrate it if there is a site where this is definitely on-topic, but Web Applications will most likely claim it is a security issue, or malware.

Comment: Since the scope of the Super User site definitely involves people that would be asked to help with this kind of problem, I thought I'd start here and see what happens.

Comment: What is not clear to me after reading your question: are the posts still occuring after what you did? I would say the most likely reasons are fixed in your Nr. 3...

Comment: No, the posts occur in waves, so it'll be a while, like weeks, before they could occur again. The way she describes it is that someone at Facebook is removing the spam, resetting her password and forcing her to change the password upon next login. Not sure this is correct though but that's what she says is happening. But no, nothing has occured since I change the things in the post, but that's not to say that they won't happen again in a few weeks time.

Comment: I'm assuming it is something she is doing, like clicking on a survey or IQ test or something, which needs her Facebook access to post the results of this survey or something and bang, the access is given, but I can't seem to find trace of this thing on her account, and she claims she doesn't do that.

Comment: When you said you "Removed two applications that were using here Facebook login", were they applications on her phone/browser/computer, or on Facebook itself? Don't they still have a bunch of "apps" that can get permission to post stuff on your behalf? Or did the disabling of all 3rd party apps & websites take care of absolutely everything on Facebook? - Correlating when the spam posts occur to what your friend's doing would help, and shutdown the computer when not used (& phones later, if needed)

Comment: They were listed on the Facebook site under (logging in to find my own list) Settings, Apps and Websites, under "Active apps and websites". On the same page, there's also a setting under Preferences which says "Turned on", which I turned off, which controls "your ability to interact with apps, websites, and games, both on and off Facebook". I'll clarify in question.

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe now just wait & see if it worked...

Comment: That is my current plan of course :) But I've been in this kind of mire previously with a similar problem that occurred every month, it got tiresome having to visit and look at a hosed computer every 4-5 weeks so I thought I'd try to nip this one in the bud ahead of time. That previous time it was a usb flash stick that had a virus on it that he had his tax software on, which he used about once a month so it took some digging to figure out why his computer got infected on such a regular basis.

Comment: I posted here in the hopes that someone knows this particular post and says "Yeah, this is the X virus, you need to go into control panel and uninstall the program that says it is Skype 14.7", or something specific like this. If this turns into a "perhaps try X, Y and Z" type of thing then it is too broad for Stack Exchange sites anyway.